# Interfaces and Abstract Classes caused method not defined for the class

Tags: dart

I'm a Dart beginner and currently working through the official Dart documentation. I am finding the section on interfaces and abstract classes a bit challenging to understand.

The documentation presents an example class, Spacecraft, which is as follows:

```
class Spacecraft {
  String name;
  DateTime? launchDate;
  int? get launchYear => launchDate?.year;

  Spacecraft(this.name, this.launchDate);
  Spacecraft.unlaunched(String name) : this(name, null);

  void describe() {
    print('Spacecraft: $name');
    var launchDate = this.launchDate;

    if (launchDate != null) { 
      int years = DateTime.now().difference(launchDate).inDays ~/ 365;
      print('Launched: $launchYear ($years years ago)');
    } else {
      print('Unlaunched');
    }
  }
}
```

The guide proceeds to introduce two additional classes, MockSpaceship and Describable. However, I believe the documentation may be missing some implementation details.

Here are the MockSpaceship and Describable classes:

```
class MockSpaceship implements Spacecraft {
 @override
 String name;

 @override
 DateTime? launchDate;

 @override
 int? get launchYear => launchDate?.year;

 MockSpaceship(this.name, this.launchDate);

 @override
 void describe() {
   print('Spacecraft: $name');
   var launchDate = this.launchDate;

   if (launchDate != null) {
     int years = DateTime.now().difference(launchDate).inDays ~/ 365;
     print('Launched: $launchYear ($years years ago)');
   } else {
     print('Unlaunched');
   }
 }
}

abstract class Describable {
 void describe();

 void describeWithEmphasis() {
   print('=========');
   describe();
   print('=========');
 }
}
```

When running the main method below:

```
void main() {
 var spacecraft = Spacecraft('Spaceship One', DateTime(2004, 9, 29));
 spacecraft.describe();
 spacecraft.describeWithEmphasis();

 var mockSpaceship = MockSpaceship('Mock Spaceship', null);
 mockSpaceship.describe();
 mockSpaceship.describeWithEmphasis();
}
```

I receive the following errors:

```
00-Introduction-Interfaces-abstract-classes.dart:48:14: Error: The method 'describeWithEmphasis' isn't defined for the class 'Spacecraft'.
 - 'Spacecraft' is from '00-Introduction-classes.dart'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'describeWithEmphasis'.
  spacecraft.describeWithEmphasis();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
00-Introduction-Interfaces-abstract-classes.dart:52:17: Error: The method 'describeWithEmphasis' isn't defined for the class 'MockSpaceship'.
 - 'MockSpaceship' is from '00-Introduction-Interfaces-abstract-classes.dart'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'describeWithEmphasis'.
  mockSpaceship.describeWithEmphasis();
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I believe the errors may be due to missing implementations of describeWithEmphasis in Spacecraft and MockSpaceship, but I'm not sure how to correctly add them.

Could someone help me understand what I'm missing and how to correct the issue? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You `extend` a subclass, you `implement` an interface.  In this case, you want:  `class Spacecraft implements Describable` (and implement all of "Describable's" methods), and class MockSpaceship extends Spacecraft` (perhaps overriding some of the methods in the base class).,

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `Describable` class, but you are not using it. It must be extended an implemented in the appropriate places.

```dart
class Spacecraft implements Describable {
  // ...
}

class MockSpaceship extends Describable implements Spacecraft {
  // ...
}
```

Consider changing the structure though. It might make more sense for `Describable` to be an interface or mixin.

Comment: Thank you, but why the API looks different [here](https://dart.dev/language#interfaces-and-abstract-classes)?